# Как автоматизиировать ввод пароля при запуске weblogic?

Tags: weblogic

Когда запускается

**startWebLogic.cmd,**

тогда предлагают ввести имя пользователя и пароль.

Как это автоматизировать, чтобы каждый раз не вводить...

**Weblogic Oracle 12c**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

созданием файла boot.properties c логином и паролем следующего содержания

```
username=логин
password=пасс
```

после после первого запуска они будут зашифрованы

Comment: по какому пути должен находится данный файл ?

Comment: {{ domains_home }}/{{ domain_name }}/servers/{{ admin_server_name }}/security/

Comment: у меня файл находится здесь :     .....:\oracle_home_develop\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\security\

Comment: ну похоже там и должно быть